# how to determine outside state (of a variable) using AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'd like to leverage AWS Lambda however I need the function I create to respond to a series of rules.

These rules could change over time.

The only way I know how to determine outside state (of a variable) using Lambda is to query an external database.

Is there a different way? Does AWS Lambda provide a global variable that every function invocation could read before executing?

Comment: plz add usecase example for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

You can utilise environment variables, see AWS docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html

However those are meant for static variables that you don't want to store in your code (like API keys for external services).

If the rules change over time while the Lambda function doesn't, you need to store the rules *somewhere* and then fetch it from that place. You can use a database or [S3 select](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-glacier-select/).

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke a Lambda function for the first time, a new container with the appropriate resources will be created to execute it, and the code for the function will be loaded into the container. This is called a Cold Start.

JavaScript, Python, Go, and Ruby are ready in about 400 milliseconds and almost always within 700 milliseconds. Java is bit slower.

Now if your is code executed and the execution time is passed and you again call the function, then Lambda may create a new container all over again. If you want to keep the function 'warm', you’ll need to ping your Lambda function every 5–15 minutes using CloudWatch event to keep it warm.

**Does AWS Lambda provide a global variable**

Yes you can use a global variable inside of AWS Lambda but remember the above two points I have mentioned. Lambda function gets data from database, iterates through a small dataset and appends to a list and use it in your function until your function is warm.

Make sure your rule should not updated frequently else this can be a total mess.

- [Best Practices for Working with AWS Lambda Functions - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html)

> Take advantage of Execution Context reuse to improve the performance
>   of your function. Make sure any externalized configuration or
>   dependencies that your code retrieves are stored and referenced
>   locally after initial execution. Limit the re-initialization of
>   variables/objects on every invocation. Instead use static
>   initialization/constructor, global/static variables and singletons.
>   Keep alive and reuse connections (HTTP, database, etc.) that were
>   established during a previous invocation

- [AWS Lambda Execution context in Java demystified](https://blog.ippon.tech/lambda-execution-context-demystified/)
- [Improving Performance From Your Lambda Function From the Use of Global Variables - Ruan Bekker's Blog](https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2018/08/27/improving-performance-from-your-lambda-function-from-the-use-of-global-variables/)
- [AWS Lambda caching issues with Global Variables - Tensult Blogs - Medium](https://medium.com/tensult/aws-lambda-function-issues-with-global-variables-eb5785d4b876)